# node text editing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

in my current scenario i can't us any server controls.

there is an input type button when click on this a span should come and act as water marker 
giving some message when you click on the message any where a run time generated text box should come in place of span.

where user can input the value and after entering if he click any where on the form the value should be assigned to new span generated run time .

An example to visualize my scenario is given below i am also making a tree but with the help js,jquery.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/nodeediting/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single container for each button, attach event on button click to add div over the input including the span with the message(position relative and zIndex > button zIndex) and on the newly inserted div attach another click handler which will replace the span with an input (actually the content of the container added so you wont have to worry about positioning) and on window.click you should check in a stored variable if you have any "popup" open and close & save. I trust you are familiar with HTML injection and $().html, $().append, $().click or $().bind since you said you are making a tree with jQuery.

After you give this a go maybe you will come up with more pinpointing questions so we could give you exact answers.

Comment: thanks rbhro i am facing a simple issue i have done this in a similar manner that u have said on the first there is a button and span in my markup in which i set my message on the double click event of span i am calling a function creating a input type and than setting its value in the span it is done properly. there is another button which is used for creating parent when i click on it

Comment: i create a span that is appened in the div with a message and also attached an dblclickevent for it which is getting fired the thing is that on the double click event i am clearing the innerhtml of the span and appending the newly created textbox that is what i am not able to achieve cut in short not able to clear the innerhtml of runtime created span i am sharing my function can u give a work around

Comment: function GetTextBoxForParent() {
        debugger
            var CountValue = $("#hdnCount").val();
            var decCount = CountValue - 1;
            var spnNew = "#spnPr" + decCount;

            spnNew.innerHTML = "";
            var elem = document.createElement("input");
            elem.type = "text";
            elem.id = "txtParent" + decCount;
            elem.setAttribute('onblur', 'SetSpanValueForParent()');
            $('#dvTree').append(elem);

        }

Comment: a similar issue was posted before. I can only guess from your variable names that you try to empty an span?! anyhow, first thing that i notice that you use a mix between plain js and jQuery, there are lots of function within jQuery to help you accomplish what you described. <br/> var spnNew = "#spnPr" + decCount; spnNew.innerHTML = "" in here something is wrong you don't actually get an html element anyhwere so you shoud replace .innerHtml='' with $(spnNew).html('') or $(spnNew).remove()